# AWK - Getting all columns where first is = $var && Date >= $date

Tags: bash, date, awk

Im new to AWK, and am trying to work out how to get all the results where the first column is equal to a variable and the date is greater than another unix timestamp formatted variable. Im using 'last' as my command. Example output is:

```
bob     pts/2        172.6.14.37     Fri July 24 12:43 - 12:17 (9+23:34)
bob     pts/2        172.6.14.37     Fri July 24 10:03 - 12:17 (5+23:34)
bob     pts/2        172.6.14.37     Tue June  4 17:55 - 09:42 (8+15:46)
bob     pts/2        172.6.14.37     Tue Mar  4 17:55 - 09:42 (8+15:46)
tim     pts/1        172.6.14.37     Mon Mar  3 16:22 - 17:30 (1+01:08)
root    pts/1        172.6.14.37     Thu Feb 27 09:38 - 09:56 (4+00:18)
```

and so I want all the results where 'bob' is in the first column. I've got

```
last -f /var/log/btmp | awk '$1 == "bob"'
```

Which gives me all bobs failed logins. Now I need to filter again where the date filed is greater than say '`20140723145100`' something like

```
last -f /var/log/btmp | awk '$1 == "bob" && $4 >= $DATE'
```

Assuming $DATE = 20140723145100 , the result I would want would be :

```
bob     pts/2        172.6.14.37     Fri July 24 12:43 - 12:17 (9+23:34)
bob     pts/2        172.6.14.37     Fri July 24 10:03 - 12:17 (5+23:34)
```

Comment: It is pretty clumsy to parse `Thu Feb 27 09:38 - 09:56` in awk or in shell especially when `year` parse is missing.

Comment: @anubhava I totally agree. Right now I'm struggling to find any other solution to this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash:

```
user=bob
since=20140623145100
last -Fa -f /var/log/btmp | 
while read line; do
    set -- $line  # no quotes here
    [[ $1 == "$user" ]] || continue
    [[ $(date -d "$3 $4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) > $since ]] && echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: I just realized that `"$3 $4 $5 $6 $7"` can be written as `"${*:3:5}"`

Comment: It's better as `d=$(date -d "$3 $4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S); [[ $d == "$since" || $d > "$since" ]]`. And `[[ ! $d < "$since" ]]` can still be valid with other cases. Or maybe just `[[ $(date -d "$3 $4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -ge $since ]]` or `(( $(date -d "$3 $4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) >= $since ))`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-s` option in `last`:

```
last -s 20140723145100
```

From `man last`:

> **-s**, --since time
>
> Display  the state of logins since specified time.  This is useful,
>   e.g., to determine easily who was logged in at a particular time.  The
>   option is often combined with --until.

And then grep for the user:

```
last -s 20140723145100 | grep "^bob"
```

---

As [you do not have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912896/awk-getting-all-columns-where-first-is-var-date-date/24913045?noredirect=1#comment38706553_24913045) the `-s` option, you can use this workaround: store all the `last` output and the output until a certain time (using `-t` option). Then compare the output:

```
last -f /var/log/btmp | grep "^bob" > everything
last -f /var/log/btmp -t "20140723145100" | grep "^bob" > upto_20140723145100

grep -vf upto_20140723145100 everything
```

Comment: For some reason I dont have -s option. Here's a pastebin of my `man last` http://pastebin.com/DVFEfugL

Comment: What about using `-t` (until time), save output and compare with the normal output of `last`?

Comment: I want everything from 'now' back until the previous time, so -t isn't of use, sadly.

Comment: Yes, I understand, what I mean is that you can get the "up to that time" and compare if with "everything". The lines appearing in "everything" and not in "up to that time" will be the "from that time".

Comment: ah I see. I guess thats similar to what I asked in my question. I still don't know how I would compare using `awk` though.

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted this, but Glens answer is more the one Ive gone with.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU Awk:

```
gawk -v user=bob -v date=20140723145100 -F '[[:space:]]{3,}| - ' '$1 == user { cmd = "exec date -d \"" $4 "\" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S"; cmd | getline d; close(cmd); if (d >= date) print }' sample
```

Output:

```
bob     pts/2        172.6.14.37     Fri July 24 12:43 - 12:17 (9+23:34)
bob     pts/2        172.6.14.37     Fri July 24 10:03 - 12:17 (5+23:34)
```

Of course actual command is `last -f /var/log/btmp | gawk -v user=bob -v date=20140723145100 ...`.

And here's a script version:

```awk
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = "[[:space:]]{3,}| - "
}
$1 == user {
    cmd = "exec date -d \"" $4 "\" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
    cmd | getline d
    close(cmd)
    if (d >= date)
        print
}
```

Usage:

```
last -f /var/log/btmp | gawk -v user=bob -v date=20140723145100 -f script.awk
```

Comment: You post a lot of good answers but they are hard to read (scrolling). Try adding a few newlines.

Comment: Thanks. Adding newlines inside single quotes works as well: it keeps the one-liner-ness and is safe to cut'n'paste.